# How to compare two similar text files and output the difference in separate text file?

Tags: c#

I have two text files `output1` and `output2`

output1 contains the following:

```
USA
New Zealand
Switzerland
Nigeria
Australia
Brazil
Kenya
Mexico
```

output2 contains

```
USA
Switzerland
Nigeria
Australia
Brazil
Mexico
China
Pakistan
```

And I would check both output1 and output2 and write the difference in a new text file like so

```
The file - New Zealand - is in output1 but not in output2
The file - Kenya - is in output1 but not in output2
The file - China - is in output2 but not in output1
The file - Pakistan - is in output2 but not in output1
```

This is the code I wrote for the first output file and repeated it for the second

```
 public void runCMD(string path1, string path2)
        {
        //path 1 should be the directory you are trying to get the files from.
        //path 2 should be the directory you want to save result.txt to.

            path2 = "C:/users/dan/desktop/";
            System.Diagnostics.Process process = new 
            System.Diagnostics.Process();
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.WindowStyle = 
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            startInfo.Arguments = "/C dir /s/b " + path1 + " > C:/users/dan/desktop/result_0.txt";
            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            process.Start();
            process.WaitForExit();

            //the goal here is to remove the path from every filename
            string line;
            System.IO.StreamWriter replace = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:/users/dan/desktop/output1.txt");
            System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:/users/dan/desktop/output_0.txt");
            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {


                //line = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(line);
                line = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(line);
                replace.WriteLine(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(line));
                //Console.WriteLine(line);
            }
            replace.Close();
            file.Close();
            File.Delete(@"C:/users/dan/desktop/output_0.txt");


        }
```

My question is how do I compare both files?

Comment: Does order matter? are the lines unique in every file?

Comment: omg, using `cmd.exe` to run `dir.exe` to store output in a **file** to read it using **streamreader** to **strip out** directory from a fullpath to store in a **second file**? [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=netframework-4.8) you can find something usefull.

Comment: the whole your code can be replaced with this: `var filenames = Directory.GetFiles(path1, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Select(Path.GetFileName).ToArray()`

Comment: order does not matter @TheGeneral, both files are very identical, just might be missing one or two lines

Answer (score 0):

You should try [diff-match-patch from Google](https://github.com/google/diff-match-patch). Here is [csharp version](https://github.com/google/diff-match-patch/tree/master/csharp).